# Does the LMA not allow logging into subscribers of beta packages?

Tags: beta-managed-package, lma, grant-login-access

We have a beta package installed in a subscriber org. From the sub org we have granted login access to our company. But from the LMA, under Subscribers, under the sub org, under Login Access Granted it continues to say "No users have granted login access."

Are we not able to use the LMA to debug beta packages in subscriber orgs?

Comment: good catch. Did you find the answer?

Comment: In my case I have released version and the same message

Comment: @Patlatus No answer yet

Comment: Then I will open Salesforce support case for my problem